# Switch between windows in Windows 10 by fuzzy matching a list of names?

Tags: windows-10

I find switching between windows with a mouse a pain. Is it possible for me to search through the titles of a window and select a window base?

Comment: What about Alt-Tab. That displays (scrolls) through available windows.

Comment: I was using the "three fingers up" gesture... but had too many windows so it was getting to be a pain to switch between things. Is alt-tab the same, is there a way to manage the windows.

Comment: Alt Tab will let you work through all open windows plus windows in the taskbar.  I do not use a touch pad so cannot say about the finger gesture. I use a mouse because I find my blue tooth mouse to work easily and well and it duplicates my track point.

Answer (score 1):

I found this open source project on github:

https://github.com/balazs4/windowswitcher

That seems to work okay on windows 10. When run this brings up a fuzzy-matching combobox.

I am using this in conjunction with [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script:

```
!#j::Run G:\My Drive\code\windows-config\switcher\windowswitcher.app.exe
```

I can then press windows+alt+j to jump to a window